# Tensorflow Model achieving no loss and no accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to build a simple model to understand a set of data. I have two arrays of input and output, in the shapes [9, 25] and [9,]. I merge these together into a tensorflow dataset, and then use a categorical cross entropy model to train. Here is my code in full:

```
from loader import loadBar
from meteo import loadWeather
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

salesData, daysOp = loadBar('June', '22')
tempData = loadWeather('June', 2022, 30, daysOp)

# Issue with unreliable last day counting
miss = len(salesData) - len(tempData)
if miss != 0:
    salesData = salesData[:-miss]

x = np.array(tempData)
y = []

for item in salesData:
    y.append(item[1])

y = np.array(y)

batch_size = 5

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y)).batch(batch_size)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(9,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(dataset, epochs=100)
```

The output I get is 100 epochs where both loss and accuracy are 0.

I have tried investigating my arrays, but when I print x and y I get correctly shaped arrays full of non-zero numbers. I can't understand where the error is as from my end it seems like I am passing in a non-zero dataset in the correct shape, but the network is training as if there is nothing to train on.

Comment: One neuron with softmax, think the possible values you can get (it is 1). There is an open PR for this kind of logical errors: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/pull/18105